# My queue table is huge, is it safe to empty it?

Tags: batch-operations, queue, database

I have launched some batch jobs that I didn't finish. Now I notice my queue table is almost 1 GB. Is it safe to empty it?

Comment: Delete the inactive batch queue entries.

Comment: Ok thanks, I also found this http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/1915/drupal-queue-update-module